# Trying to install openjdk-7 on Debian 6, dependencies provide some errors

Tags: java, apt-get

I am trying to install Java 7 on Debian 6.0 via SSH. Here is what I type and what happens when I enter the commands:
http://puu.sh/3fOj8.jpg

As you can see the apt-get -f install gives some error messages, which means I cannot continue to try to install it.

Comment: hmm, can you check which repositories are enabled on /etc/apt/sources.list ? (I think for tzdata you need the universe repo)

Answer (score 0):

Uniqu3, is this for a server? (I Noticed you're doing it by using ssh)

If it is, you should be okay using just **openjdk-7-jre-headless** as this package does not bring all the dependencies (gnome stuff mostly I believe) you're having problems with

Comment: Yes it is for a server, but here is what your recommendation does (same error messages): http://puu.sh/3fOSA.jpg

Comment: can you check which repositories are enabled on /etc/apt/sources.list ? (I think for tzdata you need the universe repo)

Comment: there is no universe repo in debian according to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113590/how-to-add-debian-universe-in-etc-apt-sources-list ?